# Problems with drupal Database Query

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-modules

i try to fetch a result with this request, which works in phpayadmin:

```
 $result_med = db_query("SELECT node.nid AS nid,
   node.created AS node_created
 FROM dr_wiwe_node node 
 LEFT JOIN dr_wiwe_content_type_classified node_data_field_classified_valid_till ON node.vid = node_data_field_classified_valid_till.vid
 WHERE ((node.type in ('classified')) AND (node.status <> 0))
    AND (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(node_data_field_classified_valid_till.field_classified_valid_till_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') >= '2010-09-16T22:34:05')
   ORDER BY node_created DESC LIMIT 1");
    var_dump($result_med);
    while ($node = db_fetch_object($result_med)) {
    //var_dump ($node);}
```

In the hardcoded php Version it returns nothing. If I var_dump $result_med, I am getting: 
resource(552) of type (mysql result)

Where is my error?

Comment: Try check this sql in query tools (like phpmyadmin). I assume your query find nothing. Set attention to your date conversations, sql tools help to you...

Comment: I already wrote in the first line, that it works in phpmyadmin.

Comment: `db_query` returns a result resource, so the `var_dump($result_med)` output looks ok. You would fetch the actual content from that resource later on, like in the partial while loop of the example. Why is the `var_dump($node)` there commented, and what does it show if you uncomment it?

Comment: Hi Henrik,it returns nothing.

Comment: yep: PHPmyAdmin returs one result.

Comment: Sorry for the dangling comment - I removed my last comment after adding the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably caused by `db_query()` treating parts of your datetime formatting strings as query parameters, which it tries to replace.

So you'll need to add additional '%' characters to your existing ones to escape them, thus preventing the parameter substitution process from trying to replace them.

See the ["If a query that has % in them" comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_query/6#comment-5114) from the db_query api documentation for an example.

A cleaner/more readable solution might be to just use '%s' placeholders for the formatting strings in the query and then add the actual formatting strings as arguments to the db_query call, as suggested by Eli.

Comment: hmmm...I changed it to this: `(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(node_data_field_classified_valid_till.field_classified_valid_till_value, '%%Y-%%m-%dT%%T'), '%%Y-%m-%d\T%%i:%%s') >= '2010-09-16T22:34:05')`

Comment: ooops...forgot some procents...now it works! Cool.Many Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Welcome to stackoverflow, BTW. You might want to accept this answer as correct, though (will help others to find it - and also some points for me ;)

Comment: It might be cleaner to use %s in the query and then use db_query to insert the correct formatting strings. That way you don't have to munge them in the source.